# My OS boots on Qemu but triple faults on VMWare

Tags: vmware, qemu, osdev

I built an operating system and it successfully booted with qemu. However when I try to boot in on VMWare, a triple fault occurs. I used a floppy to boot it in both cases. How can I find the error code of the triple fault from VMWare? I tried looking in the virtual machine logs but I couldn't find any more details.

Answer (score 0):

As you know,qemu runs programs by its virtual cpu and full virtual hardware...
but vmware will use VT(virt-tech) to get better performance and all device is running on mix-virtual mode. so it will takes you more difficulty such as running status checking will be restrict ,random config address...or whatever things.they all make your kernel into fault

To find this problem.make lots of breakpoints before where will be problem(such as running level switching,write MSR regs,config ACPI..)and run,if it still running correctly,remove next breakpoint. do debug one by one

could you give me your repo address if possible then i will  answer this question better(upload your logs is also can help me)